# What Android layout/view should I use if I am trying to display a small but unknown # of items in a grid?

Tags: android, android-layout

These will be nested grids within a larger view. And there will be a limited/small number of items in each grid. The view hierarchy should look like this:

```
<scrollview>
  <constraintlayout>
     <textview>
     <gridthing/>
     <textview>
     <gridthing/>
  </constraintlayout>
</scrollview>
```

Therefore I don't need the individual grid components to be scrollable because the parent scrollview will allow the user to navigate through all of the grids.

I don't think that a recyclerview is necessary since i don't need to scroll through a lot of items & i don't need the individual components to scroll independently. I thought of using a gridview with a height of wrap_content but you can't set a dynamic height on a gridview. That leaves me with gridlayout or tablelayout which both don't seem like the right component since those appear to be for defining layouts that are known at compile time.

What are some suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You can use an Adapter to populate your grid view. This would provide the dynamic size adjustments you require.

Comment: That provides a dynamic number of items in the grid but the size still needs to be static.

Comment: If a static view is what you want then you can simply add the views to the grid layout and make a custom view. You can then use this view wherever you like.